Passing port and pin to a function in Keil uVision
I want to pass a port and pin to a function in "Arteryf413".
void Set_relay_state_for_non_china_mode(int writeRegister_reg_num, int readRegister_reg_num,  XXX port, uint16_t pin)
{

        if(Protocol.writeRegister[writeRegister_reg_num] == 0x08) {
            gpio_bits_set(port, pin);
            if(Test.Is_Relay_On_Off_Test && Protocol.readRegister[readRegister_reg_num] == 0x00)
                Test.Total_Relay_Test_Cnt_Must_Increase = true;
            Protocol.readRegister[readRegister_reg_num] = 0x08;
        }
        else if(Protocol.writeRegister[writeRegister_reg_num] == 0x00) {
            gpio_bits_reset(port, pin);
            if(Test.Is_Relay_On_Off_Test && Protocol.readRegister[readRegister_reg_num] == 0x08)
                Test.Total_Relay_Test_Cnt_Must_Increase = true; 
            Protocol.readRegister[readRegister_reg_num] = 0x00;
        }
        

}

where:
    #define VALVE_OUT_3_Pin GPIO_PINS_4
    #define VALVE_OUT_3_GPIO_Port   GPIOC

I think pin is a uint number, but I do not know how should I pass port to the function.

From a program design point of view, why would you do this. Take a step back and re-consider the program design. If you have some manner of relay driver, then that one needs to know where everything goes GPIO-wise. And that's the only thing it should know. Then you might have another driver which is some manner of protocol handler for some bus. It only knows about that. Then on top of that you have an application layer which knows how to tie together a certain function in the protocol with a certain relay and that application-tier code calls both drivers.

I am trying to clean a dirty code. I do not want to change everything now.
But thanks for the comment.

if you are using HAL drivers for STM32 you can use:

GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx

for any other ARM MCU you can find the equivalent struct in GPIO source file of CMSIS library.
